# Troubles with django ORM, when i filter a model instance, the filter apparently isn't work like have to be

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-orm

My environment

```
Django version = 4.0.4
Python == 3.9.12
os = osx
```

I'm confused when I'm trying to make a filter on a model using a customized template tag in this way

```
@register.filter
def cart_item_count(user):
if user.is_authenticated:
    qs = Order.objects.filter(user=user, ordered=False)
    print(qs.ordered)
    if qs.exists():
        return qs[0].items.count()
    else:
       return 0
return 0
```

but even when i say in the filter that i just want the ordered=False, i make a print to ensure what value have my queryset and its prints to me True, why of this behavior?

[image: the log from the print the queryset]

It's always returning to me a true ordered order, but I want to just take that have the ordered false, because I want to show in my cart an empty cart after making the checkout POST for redirect to home o other view and update for me to an empty new cart, pls if someone can help me even with an article post about it and explain  to me what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: Assuming `ordered` is a field on your model, [QuerySet.ordered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered) is not the same as the value of the filter for the field `ordered`, they are two different things.

Comment: i'm really sorry but it's more confused for me that, it's not suppose to my queryset to be an order with the ordered field false how i asking for it my template tag how can be two different things, can you explain to me or show what's I'm not understanding about this

Comment: When you loop over your queryset you get an _instance_ of your model, try `print(qs.first().ordered)` and you'll see what you expect. `qs.ordered` tells whether there is some ordering / sorting applied on the queryset.

Comment: now it's more clear, and i make some change on my code, now. when i make the print qs now i get the false how you explain it, but now i dont know i if i have to open other question, but even now with your help i get the correct query, but in my cart still the old value for the cart, even if i refresh the page still getting my old order with all the data that i dont want

Answer (score 1):

`qs.ordered` is referring to the in-built method of QuerySet class and not to the column in the datatable.
More information can be found at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.ordered